# Generate numbers based on a table column mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following rows:

```
ID   Description  Number    
1    Test 1       4     
2    Test 2       3
3    Test 3       5
4    Test 5       6
```

How do I create my query so that if I want ID 3, it generates the following based on the Number column:

```
Count
1
2
3
4
5
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: Enable auto increment of that column

Comment: ID is already auto-incremented. What I need is a SELECT query to generate the count. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your rows are already uniquley identified. You need to query the row with id 3, and then preform an operation with php to count out to the end of the number set. 5 in this case. You could use arrays, and just loop throjgh the array for each number as well.

Comment: is it not possible to use mysql query to generate the count? :)